# Insert a text value in listview at 0 index in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, listview

I have a listview that is bind with datasource. In this listview i have to insert a hardcode value (Add new..) and a button at 0 index of listview.

Can anyone help that how can i insert a value and button at 0 index of listview.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot insert values while your control is bound to a data source.  You will have to find a way to include the value in your data source at the zeroth position and then rebind it to your control, or you could abandon the idea of using a data source and instead populate the control's items manually.

Comment: Ok.Thanks for your suggestion roryap

Answer (score 0):

you can insert value into zeroth position to a bounded ListView as Below:

```
Dim newItem As New ListViewItem
newItem.Text = "Value To Display"
ListView1.Items.Insert(0, newItem)
```